# Button still disables if a selection is still present but input box is blank

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I really need your help,

So what I am trying to accomplish, is still keeping the "Search" button enabled even if there is no text in my input box. So I guess on the key up, the code should check the select boxes for any and all selected present values, if there are none then disable continue disabling the search button.

But the problem is, I am not that brilliant enough to be able to code this properly.

Here is a pic:
[image]

Here is the HTML Markup:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  $(document).on('change', 'select', function() {

    if (this.value.length > 0) {
      $('#search').prop('disabled', false)
    } else {
      $('#search').prop('disabled', true)
    }

  });

  $(document).on('change keyup', 'input', function() {

    if (this.value.length > 0) {
      $('#search').prop('disabled', false)
    } else {
      $('#search').prop('disabled', true)
    }
  });

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  </script>

</head>

<body>
  Cars
  <select id="car">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>
  <br>
  <br>Fruits
  <select id="fruits">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="apple">apple</option>
    <option value="banana">banana</option>
    <option value="pear">pear</option>
    <option value="strawberry">strawberry</option>
    <option value="mango">mango</option>
    <option value="orange">orange</option>
  </select>
  <br>
  <br>Vegetable
  <input type="input" id="veggie">
  <br>
  <br>Number
  <input type="input" id="number">
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="button" value="search" id="search" disabled>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: So you want it initially disabled, but when the user enters something, for it to be enabled?

Comment: Try this: https://jsfiddle.net/bb70t83u/. You can remove the two functions you created and use the third example, which works. Does this fix what you are having an issue with?

Comment: Try putting your code in a `$(document).ready()` function and just before the closing `</body>` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: https://jsfiddle.net/bb70t83u/

I removed both of your function and put inside the document ready function. I only did for the `select`. You can do the same for `input`. Let me know if you need help with it.

This is based on what I think you said. Please clarify if this isn't what you are looking.

JQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $("select").on("change", function() {
    if (this.value.length > 0) {
        $('#search').prop('disabled', false)
    }
    else {
        $('#search').prop('disabled', true)
    }
  });
})
```

Comment: Your code produces the same results as the code in the top of my example. The search button remains disabled if a selection has been made in the drop down menu along with some text in the input boxes, if the selection is removed and text remains in any of the input boxes, the search button remains disabled.

Comment: So if the selection is blank but there is text in the textbox, keep the button enabled?

Comment: Your fiddle works but for some strange reason when all of the select and input boxes are cleared the search button stays enabled?

Comment: Ok I didn't take into account for that... so create another function which checks for select index and also input length and that should fix it for you. Let me know if you need help.

Comment: I'll take your help!

Comment: Did it work for you or did you need something else? If this isn't the complete solution, do let me know and clarify. Otherwise I am glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Validate entire form on any user action,

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var validateForm = function() {
    return $(':input').filter(function() {
      return this.value === '';
    }).length;
  }
  $(document).on('change keyup', ':input', function() {
    $('#search').prop('disabled', validateForm());
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Cars
<select id="car">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>Fruits
<select id="fruits">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="apple">apple</option>
  <option value="banana">banana</option>
  <option value="pear">pear</option>
  <option value="strawberry">strawberry</option>
  <option value="mango">mango</option>
  <option value="orange">orange</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>Vegetable
<input type="input" id="veggie">
<br>
<br>Number
<input type="input" id="number">
<br>
<br>
<input type="button" value="search" id="search" disabled>
```

Comment: Your code just leaves the search button disabled all of the time.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your code in a `$(document).ready()` function.

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('change', 'select', function() {

      if (this.value.length > 0 || $('input').value.lenght > 0) {
        $('#search').prop('disabled', false)
      } else {
        $('#search').prop('disabled', true)
      }

  });

  $(document).on('change keyup', 'input', function() {

    if (this.value.length > 0 || $('select').value.lenght > 0) {
      $('#search').prop('disabled', false)
    } else {
      $('#search').prop('disabled', true)
    }
  });
})
</script>
<!--- Just before body tag --->
</body>
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/z4kpnyq0/)

Comment: Doesn't work. It produces the same results as that of mine in my post.

Comment: @BobbyJones are you getting any errors in your console?